# Authentication logic in Asp.Net MVC with encoded query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an `Asp.Net MVC 5` application and the Login process occurs outside of the application.

If a user wants to enter the application, an encoded query string will be passed to the application and this value is sent back to one of their web services, it will decode the query string and send a C# object as a result. Also, it is important to know that the application will opened **inside an iframe** with **https** enabled.

I want to store this data in some secure place and then send the object to some action methods with `ModelBinder`. There is not any problem but I don't know what to use? Forms Authentication or not? Cookie or Session? And how can these be used?

Thanks.